# Process plymouth-upstart-bridge keeps terminating

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

On Ubuntu 14.0.4, many people have noticed that process `plymouth-upstart-bridge` keeps respawning during the boot. Link http://www.unrelatedshit.com/2014/07/30/kvm-too-fast-for-plymouth-upstart-bridge/ suggests that we add `sleep 2` at the end of `/etc/init/plymouth-upstart-bridge` conf file. However, adding this line results in a new error "unknown stanza." Is there a workaround or a fix for this process-respawning problem? Regards.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `post-stop exec sleep 2` instead.

(source: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#delay-respawn-of-a-job)

This also should do the job

```
script
    sleep 2
end script
```

Comment: How can you edit the plymouth conf file when your system isn't booting? In my case, the machine just hangs after showing the respawn message.

Comment: Try using a live-cd to boot, then look for ansers/question on how to modify files that are on your HD

Comment: thanks but i found a better solution. go to root terminal from recovery mode and edit from there. cheers.